# Calling related name models in query (Q) "Django"

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have profile model like :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
```

and I have a search view like :

```
def users_search_view(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    users = User.objects.filter(Q(email__icontains=query)|Q(username__icontains=query),is_superuser=False,is_staff=False)
    ctx = {'users':users,
    'q':query}
    return render(request,"staff/users_search.html", ctx)
```

I want to have search by first name and also last name from Profile model, in my search, How can I make something like `Q(email__icontains=query)` for related modals ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
User.objects.filter(Q(profile__first_name__icontains=query) | Q(profile__last_name__icontains=query) | Q(email__icontains=query) | Q(username__icontains=query),is_superuser=False,is_staff=False)
```

One can use double underscores (`__`) to look "through" relations. This will result in a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` where we thus filter on the related `Profile` record for that `User`.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep adding Q objects to your filter and use dunder (`__`) to access related fields.

E.g. `User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=q) | Q(profile__first_name__icontains=q))`